# Alternatives to SimpleTest's SimpleBrowser

Tags: php, browser

I was working on and using [Simple Browser](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html) from the Simple Test framework when I found out that I need to use CSS selectors to access some element.

Unfortunately, I discovered in the [overview](http://www.simpletest.org/en/overview.html) that it does not support CSS selectors currently.

Are there any alternatives to this? I am simply looking for standalone browser that can be scripted via PHP that supports CSS selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your options:

- [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) - this is a PHP-based "browser" for testing. It sounds very similar to Simple Browser.
- [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/) - Two non-PHP tools for automating testing in a browser. They can both drive automated tests in any of the main-stream browsers.
- [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/) - A PHP-based testing tool that can drive any of the above tools to test your site in a browser via a PHP script. I suspect this is what you're looking for, probably in conjunction with Goutte if you want to replicate what you're already doing. (although I find it works better with Sahi and a real browser).
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) - a "headless" browser, which is specifically designed for writing browser test scripts. It's not PHP-based, but for automated testing it is possibly the best tool available. Test in a real browser, but without the overhead of an actual UI to display, and with features designed to make testing easier. If you want to use it in PHP, it can be driven via Sahi, and thus via Mink, so you can do it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I picked Mink because it was the best that I tried. It was good until I get to aspx pages though. I get an bad header on those when trying to submit a form.

Comment: which mink driver are you using? maybe try a different one. Mink itself just drives the automation tool (sahi, goutte, etc), and should be fairly isolated from stuff like that.

Comment: Turns out that for aspx pages, I need to add some headers to make them work.

Comment: @arvinsim, what were the headers you added? I'm using Goutte on SSL ASP pages, and I'm getting "Bad Request (Invalid Header Name)" back. Oddly I can get the same page via `wget --no-check-certificate` no problem, so perhaps there's some browser default header that these tools don't usually send?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I discovered in the overview that it does not support CSS selectors currently.

SimpleTest does not support CSS selectors out-of-the-box, but an extension exists for a long time...

https://github.com/simpletest/simpletest/blob/master/extensions/dom_tester/css_selector.php